# rails 4 multiple autocomplete with nested attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, nested-forms

**Issue**
User can choose languages

**Models**
User

```
      has_many :fluent_languages, foreign_key: 'user_id'
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :fluent_languages,
                                   allow_destroy: true,
                                   reject_if: proc { |attributes|     attributes['user_id'].blank? || attributes['language_id'].blank? }
```

FluentLanguage

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
```

Language

```
has_many :fluent_languages, foreign_key: 'language_id'
```

I wish select look like this
 https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple

My try:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :fluent_languages do |fluent_language| %>
                              <%= fluent_language.text_field :user_id, :type => 'hidden' %>
                              <%= fluent_language.autocomplete_field :language_id, autocomplete_language_language_users_path, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :placeholder => 'Choose languages' %>
                              <% end %>
```

It's record to params next:

```
"7"=>{"user_id"=>"15", "language_id"=>["English,"]}}
```

but correct data look like this:

```
"4"=>{"user_id"=>"15", "language_id"=>["1995"], "id"=>"1"}
```

Another problem in my code - multiselect with autocomplete render for each record in FluentLanguage. And another one - default data is languages ids from FluentLanguage instead language title from languages table.

What design for this issue are you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked several questions, I will answer the most important one regarding design. Once you have a good data model in place, the solutions for getting the form to do what you want will be easier.

It appears that you have a has_many_through relationship between User and Language with FluentLanguage as the through table, which needs to be defined.

```
class User
  has_many :fluent_languages
  has_many :languages, through: fluent_languages
end

class Language
  has_many :fluent_languages
  has_many :users, through: fluent_languages
end

class FluentLanguage
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You will need to run migrations to update your schema. The [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is a good source for how a has_many_through relationship works and how to build it. The [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) are also very useful.

Comment: Please would you mark my answer as accepted as I'm trying to get my next badge. If you have any questions about the form let me know. Thanks.

Comment: To the left of my answer is a grey triangle pointing up, a grey triangle pointing down and a grey check mark. Click the check mark to accept the answer and click the triangle pointing up. Thx